# Run installed windows within linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I dual-boot Windows 10 and OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, but I do most of what I do on linux. My question is, is there a way to run the windows installed on my computer within linux, like a guest in a virtual machine ? The difference here is that the windows I'll run would not be a freshly-installed virtual system, but a limited version (so as to not conflict with the hosting system) of the real installed system with all its configurations as a guest. A simple use case for that would be to run a windows executable smoothly without needing a risky, unwarranted solution like wine  because why would I need wine when I have a legitimate copy of windows. So, can that be done ? This is only a convenience thing, to avoid rebooting multiple times to have a simple task done.

Comment: Sorry, no. A kernel needs dedicated hardware access unless there is a virtualization layer emulating it, and the kernel has drivers targeting that virtualization layer. Standard PC hardware cannot run two OSs at once, so there is no way for two kernels to access the same hardware at the same time. One of them must become subservient to the other.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/168156/how-to-use-a-real-partition-with-windows-7-installed-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, I know that. What I'm looking for is a way to configure a virtual machine to run an existing, installed, real system.

Comment: Well even if you tried to map the raw physical hard disk to a virtual one, once you do that you won't be able to boot the OS on hardware again, due to drivers. Just something to consider.

Comment: While it’s possible to run an OS both on hardware and in a virtual machine, Windows isn’t suited for this. It doesn’t cope well with “switch the disk to a different PC”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create  pointer to hardware partition instead of real virtual disk, then create virtual machine which would boot from that .vmdk.

> The command you want is
>
> `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename Win7.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda -partitions 1`
>
> This will create a special VMDK virtual disk file (Win7.vmdk) which is actually a pointer to the host disk partition /dev/sda1.

The problem with that might be that Windows will not just boot on different hardware, also:

> (b) you may get problems with Windows Activation depending on your license key and whether Windows decides that the detected 'hardware' has significantly changed

Quotes taken from [How to use a real partition with Windows 7 installed, in a virtualbox vm?](https://askubuntu.com/a/168167/648806) by [StarNamer](https://askubuntu.com/users/77740/starnamer)

Comment: Which one of those 4 answers are you saying answer this question?  What part of one of those 4 answers are you saying is helpful?  How about a quote and citation, within the body of your answer, so if for some odd reason that question is deleted we have the answer within the body of your answer?  Why do I feel like I repeat these same comments, about how an answer should quote and cite the relevant information within the body of an answer, if a reference link is going to be used?

Comment: @Ramhound last time i cited an answer from question on another StackExchange site (with link to it and another one to author and editors) someone told me not do do this, so linking to specified answer instead.

Comment: If you quoted and cited an answer on Superuser, instead of flagging the question as a duplicate, that might have been the reason somebody might have said that.  I find it hard to believe, anyone told you, not to quote and cite the contents of another answer though.

Comment: @Ramhound i cited from StackOverflow and got downvoted, that's why now i only link to other StackExchange sites. http://imgur.com/a/G298K

Comment: If you read what Barlop actually said, you should have left a comment to the answer, instead of quoting and citing the answer itself.  I don't know what the question is, so I can't say if there is any truth, to the rest of their statement.  Additionally, the answer you quoted and cited in that answer in the image is extremly poor, its primarly commentary.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the easiest thing to do is run Win7 or 10 and the create a Hyper-V instance within windows to launch your Linux install. The Linux and windows would both be avail and easily swapped between. Or you could use Parallels as the hypervisor and load MacOS (Linux under the covers) and then load windows 7 or 10. you mealy swipe the screen across between OSs.

Good luck.